# Get adapter from OnActivityCreate()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listview, notifydatasetchanged

I am trying to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on an adapter in a Fragment, from the MainActivity, in order to refresh the view/list after changing data. I create the adapter inside `OnActivityCreate()`, so I'm having trouble finding out how I can get the adapter, so that I can create a method to call that will have `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

**Fragment**

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    String[] names = new String[] { "name1", "name1", "name1" };
    String[] values = new String[] { "value1", "value2", "value3" };
    MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(getActivity(), names, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I have tried creating a method in the Fragment and passing `adapter` to it but I'm not able to call that from the Main Activity. Also `getListAdapter()` isn't letting me call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Very confused here, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make it visible for the entire Activity.

```java
... MyClass {

    private MyArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        String[] names = new String[] { "name1", "name1", "name1" };
        String[] values = new String[] { "value1", "value2", "value3" };
        adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(getActivity(), names, values);
       setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    // Another method
    private void myMethod() {
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think his question was to notify from the MainActivity not from the fragment. I would continue with your solution and make the myMethod public. You should also have the reference to the fragment saved in MainActivity and then use that to call the myMethod which in turn will call the notify on adapter.